# What version of the Realtek Audio driver is my system using?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, realtek, ubuntu-drivers

I am new in Linux and I would like to ask, does anyone know how to find out which Realtek Audio driver is installed in Ubuntu?

In Windows we can see the version of Realtek Audio Driver by using device management. Like this:

[image: Sample in Device Management]

How about in Ubuntu? Is there a way to view these information? How about the other drivers?

Comment: Hello, I checked this but i think that it does not answer the question on how to get the version of the driver currently installed in your system.

Comment: There is no separate Realtek driver in linux. So the driver version is the kernel version.

Comment: @EliahKagan I wrote an answer, but I am sure it is a dupe of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realtek audio device is supported by Linux kernel. There is no separate driver in Ubuntu like in Windows.

That's why the driver version will be the kernel version.

You can check it by running

```
lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
```

Comment: Hello sir @Pilot6, thank you for this.
I am new in Linux, and can you explain to me what you mean when you said that
"the driver version will be the kernel version"?

Also I tried the command that you provided and this is the result.
[https://ibb.co/B4ZpvhY]

Why is it indicated in the result of the command that you provided says "Intel Corporation Device", when what I am looking for is the Realtek Audio Driver. Does this mean that this is already the Realtek Audio Driver I am looking for?

Can I ask for your advise regarding this?

Comment: You link is empty. You can post output to your question. Anyway your audio device is directly supported by Linux kernel. So there is no "driver version". There is kernel version, that can be seen by `uname -a`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the enlightening me. So if I want to upgrade or downgrade my Realtek Version, all I need to do is update/downgrade my kernel?

Regarding my first comment try this link if the posted one does not work [https://imgur.com/a/aMEfqCK]..

The output is:
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9dc8] (rev 11)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2292]
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev

Comment: Why do you need to upgrade or downgrade "Realtek version"? Windows solutions won't work on Linux.

Comment: I am testing Windos and Linux, and in Windows I check if an error is also occuring in a previous version of the driver. Which is why I want to know the current driver version in ubuntu and how to update/downgrade it. It seems that you already answered my question regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a specific question regarding problems with some specific kernel, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help.