# Headphone Audio/Mic Problem in Kubuntu

Tags: sound, kubuntu, microphone, samsung

I having audio problems in Kubuntu. My headphone is not working correctly. When connected, no sound output and mic audio comes out of speaker.
When I switch audio input, to "Internal Microphone"(Integrated Web Cam), the sound comes out normally from headphone.

```
My laptop is: Sansung Book E20 - NP550XCJ-KO2BR
Sound Card: HDA Intel PCH, in agreement alsa-mixer
Driver Installed and Used: Realtek ALC897, in agreement alsa-mixer
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-28-generic
lspci -v: 
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20) (prog-if 80)
        DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c195
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 134
        Memory at 6001140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 6001000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

The problem not is headphone, he works in smartphones and Windows. In Windows, i used Samsung Update for update audio driver and resolve a audio problem similar.

I opened, in [national forum](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/PC-Configuration/Problema-com-microfone-no-alto-falantes-do-fone-de-ouvido), this question too. But I no  success.

Thankful for any help. And sorry, I am brasilian and i am learning english.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you are saying that when you plug in to the headphone jack, system doesn't switch audio output automatically from speaker to headphone. And you want to set it so?

Comment: No, the system recognizes the headset, it appears in the system settings. What happens is that the headset has a microphone however for some reason it does not pick up the sound from the microphone but from the speakers of the headset. Look at this image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMk5DThoCJjYGNh4KUw96o5my2OB-q-C/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image: 3.5 mm mini plug]

A 3.5 mm miniture audio jack has 3 types or more by length.
And the ordinary headphone jack is designed for TRS except the smartphone audio jack should be used for a headphone with mic and it must be TRRS.

Linux doesn't have a seperate driver for each one.
See: [What version of the Realtek Audio driver is my system using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164506/what-version-of-the-realtek-audio-driver-is-my-system-using)

A USB headphone&mic adoptor can do this workaround.
You can ask a new question or find the Q&A how you modifiy your own custom kernel to obtain a proper driver for TRRS audio jack.